How to get Freeradius to trust certs created else ware
I run a lab for testing for customers. I am trying to load the certs my customer has made into my freeradius so I can test TTLS and TLS wifi connections in real time without my customers help. I loaded the certs into freeradius and changed the eap file to point to my new certs folder.I keep getting "unknown CA" error. Below is the output. Any thoughts?
eap: Expiring EAP session with state 0x782ce7497c2aeaa0
(5) eap: Finished EAP session with state 0x782ce7497c2aeaa0
(5) eap: Previous EAP request found for state 0x782ce7497c2aeaa0, released from the list
(5) eap: Peer sent packet with method EAP TLS (13)
(5) eap: Calling submodule eap_tls to process data
(5) eap_tls: Continuing EAP-TLS
(5) eap_tls: [eaptls verify] = ok
(5) eap_tls: Done initial handshake
(5) eap_tls: <<< recv TLS 1.2  [length 0002]
(5) eap_tls: ERROR: TLS Alert read:fatal:unknown CA
(5) eap_tls: TLS_accept: Need to read more data: error
(5) eap_tls: ERROR: Failed in FUNCTION (SSL_read): error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
(5) eap_tls: In SSL Handshake Phase
(5) eap_tls: In SSL Accept mode
(5) eap_tls: SSL Application Data
(5) eap_tls: ERROR: TLS failed during operation
(5) eap_tls: ERROR: [eaptls process] = fail
(5) eap: ERROR: Failed continuing EAP TLS (13) session.  EAP sub-module failed
(5) eap: Sending EAP Failure (code 4) ID 6 length 4
(5) eap: Failed in EAP select
(5)     [eap] = invalid
(5)   } # authenticate = invalid
(5) Failed to authenticate the user
(5) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(5) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(5)   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
I am thinking there is another place I need to change to make freeradius trust the new certs. Not sure where?
